# Are there any papers describe why flex is faster than lex?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical

flex is called the "fast" lexical analyzer, but I can not find any document that explains why it is faster than lex. flex has a manual, but it focus on its usage instead of its internals. Could any experts in this field give some help please? Either an explanation about flex's performance improvements or a link to it is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from Vern Paxson, and he allows it being shared here.

> Alas, this would take quite a bit of time to sketch in any sort of
>   useful detail, as there are a number of techniques that contribute to
>   its performance.  I wrote a paper about it a loooong time ago (mid
>   80s!) but don't have a copy of it.  Evidently you can buy it from:
>
> ```
>     http://www.ntis.gov/search/product.aspx?ABBR=DE85000703
> ```
>
> Sorry not to be of more help ...

Answer (score 1):

To add to Vern's statement, *flex* does a lot better job of table compression, providing several different space/time tradeoffs, and its inner loop is also considerably faster than *lex's*.

According to a (Usenet?) paper by van Jacobsen in the 1980s, *lex* was largely written by an AT&T intern. VJ described how its inner loop could be reduced from several dozen instructions to about three.

Vern Paxon wrote *flex* for what he described at the time as the fastest data acquisition applications in the world. Not sure if I should go into more details here.

I had the privilege of helping Vern with the 8-bit version, as I was working in compilers that had to scan Kanji and Katakana at the time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not so sure `flex` is so much faster than the AT&T version `lex`. Both programs have been developed independently and to avoid confusion with the *official* version, the authors of `flex` probably choose a slightly different name. They might have intended to generate faster scanners, which is also suggested by a couple of options to trade space for time. Also they motivate making `%option yylineno` (and a few other features) optional with the speed of the generated scanner.

Whether the slight differences in speed for such scanners are still relevant is debatable. I couldn't find any official statement on the choice of name either, so I guess you'd have to ask the original authors [Jef Poskanzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jef_Poskanzer) and/or [Vern Paxson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vern_Paxson). If you find them and get an answer, then please let us know here. History of software is interesting and you can still get the answer first hand.

Comment: Very good advice. I just sent this question/link to Vern Paxson. Hopefully we can get some comments.

Comment: I added the comments from Vern Paxson.

Comment: If it wasn't, it wouldn't have been funded, let alone written.